# read xml file in another computer using c#

Tags: c#, .net, sockets

Sorry about my bad English.
I have 2 computers, name "computer A" and "computer B", both are in a  LAN.
I have 2 projects. 1 at computer A and the other at computer B.
Computer B has a "info.xml" file in project's bin folder.
I want the project A could read that file using C#.
Which method should i use?
Thank you for taking your time.
This is my "Computer A" code

```
namespace Client
{
    class Program
    {
        private const int BUFFER_SIZE = 1024;
        private const int PORT_NUMBER = 7826;
        public static string xmlsvinfo = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\data\\serverinfo.xml";
        public static string xmlpath = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\data\\gamesinfo.xml";
        static ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                // IPAddress address = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");
                IPEndPoint iep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), PORT_NUMBER);

                Socket client = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
                client.Connect(iep);
                string command = "checkupdate";
                while (!command.Equals("quit"))
                {
                    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
                    doc.Load(xmlsvinfo);
                    XmlNode node = doc.SelectSingleNode(@"root/UPDATE");
                    string clupdate = node.InnerText;
                    // gui lenh
                    if (command == "update")
                    {
                        XmlDocument docx = new XmlDocument();
                        docx.Load(xmlpath);
                        docx.DocumentElement.RemoveAll();
                        docx.Save(xmlpath);
                        string[] mtam = new string[4];
                        client.Send(encoding.GetBytes(command));
                        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
                            {
                                byte[] data = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
                                int rec = client.Receive(data);
                                mtam[i] = encoding.GetString(data, 0, rec);
                                Console.WriteLine("da nhan: " + mtam[i]);
                            }
                        write_xml(mtam[0], mtam[1], mtam[2], mtam[3]);
                        Console.ReadLine();
                        client.Close();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        client.Send(encoding.GetBytes(command));
                        byte[] data = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
                        int rec = client.Receive(data);
                        Console.WriteLine("Server version: " + encoding.GetString(data, 0, rec) + "\nClient version: " + clupdate);
                        if (clupdate == encoding.GetString(data, 0, rec))
                        {
                            command = "quit";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            command = "update";
                            clupdate = encoding.GetString(data, 0, rec);
                            node.InnerText = clupdate;
                            doc.Save(xmlsvinfo);
                        }
                        // Console.ReadLine();
                    }
                }

                client.Close();
                // Console.ReadLine();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error: " + ex);
                // Console.ReadLine();
            }
```

And here is "Computer B"

```
namespace Server
{
    class Program
    {
        private const int BUFFER_SIZE = 1024;
        private const int PORT_NUMBER = 7826;
        public static string xmlsvinfo = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\data\\serverinfo.xml";
        public static string xmlpath = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\data\\gamesinfo.xml";

        static ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                IPEndPoint iep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), PORT_NUMBER);

                Console.WriteLine("waiting for client...");

                Socket server = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

                server.Bind(iep);
                server.Listen(10);

                Socket client = server.Accept();
                Console.WriteLine("Accepted: " + client.RemoteEndPoint.ToString());

                byte[] data = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
                string result = "";
                while (true)
                {
                    int rec = client.Receive(data);
                    string command = encoding.GetString(data, 0, rec);
                    Console.WriteLine("Client: " + command);
                    if (command.Equals("checkupdate"))
                    {
                        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
                        doc.Load(xmlsvinfo);
                        XmlNode node = doc.SelectSingleNode(@"root/UPDATE");
                        result = node.InnerText;
                    }
                    else if (command.Equals("update"))
                    {
                        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
                        doc.Load(xmlpath);
                        XmlNodeList nodelist = doc.GetElementsByTagName("gameinfor");
                        string dem = nodelist.Count.ToString();
                        client.Send(encoding.GetBytes(dem));
                        string dat = string.Empty;
                        for(int i = 0; i<nodelist.Count; i++)
                        {
                            for(int j= 0; j<4; j++)
                            {
                                dat = nodelist[i].ChildNodes.Item(j).InnerText;
                                client.Send(encoding.GetBytes(dat));
                                Console.WriteLine("sending " + dat);
                            }
                        }
                        Console.ReadLine();
                        client.Close();
                        break;
                    }
                    else if (command.Equals("quit"))
                    {
                        client.Close();
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        result = "wrong command";
                    }
                    client.Send(encoding.GetBytes(result));
                    Console.ReadLine();
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error: " + ex);
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
```

I've tried to read my file in computer B then send it through socket. computer A will recieved it and write it to another xml file in computer A. but it won't work.

Here is also my "writexml" method

```
static void write_xml(string id, string name, string cata, string path)
        {
            XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
            xmlDoc.Load(xmlpath);

            XmlNode gameinfor = xmlDoc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "gameinfor", null);

            XmlNode nodeId = xmlDoc.CreateElement("ID_Game");
            nodeId.InnerText = id;

            XmlNode nodegamename = xmlDoc.CreateElement("Tên_Game");
            nodegamename.InnerText = name;

            XmlNode nodetheloai = xmlDoc.CreateElement("Thể_Loại");
            nodetheloai.InnerText = cata;

            XmlNode nodegamepath = xmlDoc.CreateElement("Path");
            nodegamepath.InnerText = path;

            gameinfor.AppendChild(nodeId);
            gameinfor.AppendChild(nodegamename);
            gameinfor.AppendChild(nodetheloai);
            gameinfor.AppendChild(nodegamepath);

            xmlDoc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(gameinfor);
            xmlDoc.Save(xmlpath);

        }
```

Comment: "Which method should I use?" - I don't think there is a specific pre-built method to do exactly that. You'd probably need to write your own.

Comment: Yes, i know that but after 3 days stuck with this things, i don't know what i have to do to slove this.

Comment: As I'm sure you're aware, this is a question/answer site (not a forum, or discussion board) for concrete programming problems. You should focus on your current hurdle, show us the code you have so far (as little as possible to demonstrate the problem fully), describe your expectations, and problem with the current code.

Comment: Okay, i understand. i'll show up my code right now.

Comment: Can you clarify _"but it won't work."_? Use the debugger to step through the code if you need to to get more information.

Comment: I mean, my code is work. but the result is bad. after 1st loop, the client doesn't receive the right text.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want a file to be read just read a file using the path of the file. There's no need to use sockets or so to do this. On the other hand, if you want to get some information from a computer to another I suggest using sockets.

Example of how to read a file in another computer (LAN) without sockets.

```
using (var file = File.Open("//server/path/file.txt")) {...}
```

Comment: Do i need to share the folder in "Server" computer?

Comment: Yes, @RyoDejan. You need a network shared location or Shared folder to read the file.

Comment: @RyoDejan the "//" on the beggining of the path is a prefix that indicate that the file is in a shared folder. It's a UNC Windows file path.